# image.style.left is not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Getting an error saying too much recursion. The actually has to move the image. Its giving the same error even if I am trying to clear the timeout.

Note:  I found out that the_image.style.left is not moving the image whatsoever.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.image_style{left:x}
</style>
<script>
var the_timer, x_position = 0, my_image;
function move_image(){
        my_image = document.getElementById("imag");
        x_position = x_position+1;
        my_image.style.left = x_position;
        the_timer = setTimeout(move_image(), 200);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onclick="move_image()">
<img src = "desert.jpg" id = "imag"
        style="position:obsolute; width:300px; height:400px; left:0">
        <script>
                my_image = document.getElementById("imag");
                alert(my_image.style.left);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position:obsolute;` to `position:absolute;`.

Comment: You have a typo. Its `absolute` not `obsolute`

Comment: It seems to work https://fiddle.jshell.net/attp1qcx/
my_image.style.left is 0px like it should be

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setInterval` instead of `setTimeOut`. Right now you are calling function within function which is a never ending process that's why you are getting error.

Also `left` property needs value in `px` while you are assigning only a number which will not move the image.

```
setInterval(function () { move_image() }, '1000');

function move_image() {

        my_image = document.getElementById("imag");
        x_position = x_position + 1;
        my_image.style.left = x_position + "px";
        console.log(x_position);

    }
```